# Why does Delphi unclear increases the refcount of the last element in the list of interfaces?

Tags: delphi, reference-counting

I use Delphi 2007 and it almost completely blows my mind up with interface reference counting. This small code chunk shows the problem:

```
program intf;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes;

type
  IMyIntf = interface(IInterface)
  ['{3DE76B13-1F8D-4BCE-914E-7E3B7FB0FA5A}']
    function GetSelf: TObject;
  end;

  TMyObj = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyIntf)
  private
    FI: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(i: Integer);
    function GetSelf: TObject;
    property I: Integer read FI;
  end;

var
  i, j: Integer;
  il: TInterfaceList;
  ii: IInterface;
  MyObj: TMyObj;
  IMyObj: IMyIntf;

constructor TMyObj.Create(i: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FI := i;
end;

function TMyObj.GetSelf: TObject;
begin
  Result := Self;
end;

begin
  // create list of interfaced objects and populate it
  il := TInterfaceList.Create;
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    il.Add(TMyObj.Create(i));

  for j := 1 to 2 do begin
    writeln('start loop #', j);
    i := 1;
    for ii in il do begin
      if ii.QueryInterface(IMyIntf, IMyObj) <> 0 then
        halt(1);
      MyObj := TMyObj(IMyObj.GetSelf);
      // release unnecessary IMyIntf, good housekeeping!
      IMyObj := nil;
      writeln('object #', i, ': ', MyObj.I, ', refcount: ', MyObj.RefCount);
      Inc(i);
    end;
    writeln('end loop #', j);
  end;
end.
```

Everything is Ok and as expected after this program run, here is the output:

```
start loop #1
object #1: 1, refcount: 3
object #2: 2, refcount: 3
object #3: 3, refcount: 3
end loop #1
*****
start loop #2
object #1: 1, refcount: 3
object #2: 2, refcount: 3
object #3: 3, refcount: 3
end loop #2
*****
```

But if I copy inner `for ii in il` loop and paste it right after the previous **entirely the same** one `for ii in il` loop Delphi automatic reference counting of the TInterfaceList elements breaks at the last element for some reason:

```
// skipped
  for j := 1 to 2 do begin
    writeln('start first loop #', j);
    i := 1;
    for ii in il do begin
      if ii.QueryInterface(IMyIntf, IMyObj) <> 0 then
        halt(1);
      MyObj := TMyObj(IMyObj.GetSelf);
      // release unnecessary IMyIntf, good housekeeping!
      IMyObj := nil;
      writeln('object #', i, ': ', MyObj.I, ', refcount: ', MyObj.RefCount);
      Inc(i);
    end;

    writeln('end first loop #', j);
    writeln('*****');

    writeln('start second loop #', j);
    i := 1;
    for ii in il do begin
      if ii.QueryInterface(IMyIntf, IMyObj) <> 0 then
        halt(1);
      MyObj := TMyObj(IMyObj.GetSelf);
      // release unnecessary IMyIntf, good housekeeping!
      IMyObj := nil;
      writeln('object #', i, ': ', MyObj.I, ', refcount: ', MyObj.RefCount);
      Inc(i);
    end;
    writeln('end second loop #', j);
  end;
// skipped
```

Here is the output, keep attention at object #3 after first loop:

```
start first loop #1
object #1: 1, refcount: 3
object #2: 2, refcount: 3
object #3: 3, refcount: 3
end first loop #1
*****
start second loop #1
object #1: 1, refcount: 3
object #2: 2, refcount: 3
object #3: 3, refcount: 4
end second loop #1
start first loop #2
object #1: 1, refcount: 3
object #2: 2, refcount: 3
object #3: 3, refcount: 4
end first loop #2
*****
start second loop #2
object #1: 1, refcount: 3
object #2: 2, refcount: 3
object #3: 3, refcount: 4
end second loop #2
```

Oops! The last element RefCount turned to 4 instead of 3 **right after first loop**. Any additional loop after the first one breaks away Delphi automatic reference counting. If I copy'n'paste loop body again the last element RefCount becomes 5, if I copy'n'paste loop body once again the last element RefCount becomes 6 and so on -- how many loops I add so many times the last element RefCount becomes 1 more larger than should be.

Why? Either I miss something or something is unclear for me but what exactly?

Thanx in advance for any help/suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enumerator object that is used to implement the `for/in` loop is holding a reference to the final object in the list. During enumeration, the enumerator object holds a reference to the current object. Once the enumeration has completed, this reference to the current object is in fact a reference to the final object.

The enumerator object is only destroyed when it goes out of scope. In this program the enumerator object has global scope. So it persists until the end of the program. Each time you add another loop you add another enumerator.

Comment: Aha! I suspected something like that. I tried to free enumerator variable assigning nil to it (i.e. doing 'ii := nil' right after loop), I thought that nil assignment releases last list element refcounter but it did not, refcounter of the last element was still the same increased. So assigning of nil to enumerator variable won't help anyway,  it is exactly necessary that the variable goes out of scope?

Comment: You have no access to the enumerator object. You've no way to influence it all you can do is wait until scope ends. Is there. A problem beyond just your desire to understand?

Comment: To elaborate, `ii` is separate from the enumerator object's `current` property. The latter is hidden from you and only the compiler sees it.

Comment: Yes, but the enumerator object has a reference too. And you don't have any access to the enumerator object.

Comment: Thank you, David! I got it. I understand that I cannot change `ii` inside loop, I tried to modify enumerator variable **rigth after loop** `ii := nil` with no help. I didn't know about scope handling of such cases, thank you again a lot!

Comment: That's not the private variable held by the enumerator object. You cannot gain access to that.